# Best ORM for Adobe Air / Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air, adobe, orm

I'm not sure what I'm missing here, but I can't find a reliable ORM for AIR.

The ones I find are not documented well and don't seem to have a solid following. Is a solid ORM non-existant at this point?

Ones I'm aware of:
http://flexorm.riaforge.org/
http://code.google.com/p/airorm/
http://code.google.com/p/air-activerecord/

Comment: There can only be an ORM for AIR. In Flex you still need a backend like PHP. In this backend you can use the existing ORMs like Propel or Doctrine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I Never used it but have a look at the Cairngorm Persistance Library :

http://sourceforge.net/adobe/cairngorm/wiki/HowtoUsetheCairngormPersistenceLibrary/

Looks like what you're looking for :

"The Persistence library eases the communication between an Adobe AIR application and an SQLite database. Both use different type systems (relational SQL versus object-oriented ActionScript). This Object Relational Mapping (ORM) library follows an iBATIS approach."

Comment: Nice! I haven't seen this one. This looks promising. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check out Flextrine at www.flextrine.com

This is a client/server Flex ORM solution that integrates with Doctrine 2.

Answer (score 0):

ORM frameworks are designed to help access a database.  Since Flex has no direct access to a database, an ORM framework would be extremely limited.

I assume the projects you link to are for dealing with AIR and the embedded SQLLite database.

There are plugins for Flash Builder that will generate value objects based on the database you specify.  Originally they were just for ColdFusion, but I think they've expanded to include other technologies.  However, I would not consider these "code generators" the same as an ORM.

Comment: Just to clarify, I did state "I can't find a reliable ORM for AIR", so Flex isn't really the factor. I included Flex in my question to open the door for ActionScript options.

I am not looking for a code generator. Only a true ORM solution, like ActiveRecord or Hibernate.

Comment: I'm guilty of not reading carefully; sorry about that. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [FxORM](https://github.com/kennichi/FxORM). It has nice documentation with examples if you follow the link.